# Страница пропущенных строк перевода

Tags: поддержка, локализация, transifex

Не так давно появилась новая страница для всех, кто заинтересован в улучшении и переводе интерфейса сайта.

### [Страница пропущенных строк перевода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)

Любой участник имеет доступ к странице, каких–либо привилегий не требуется. Каждая запись на странице имеет несколько ссылок:

- ссылку, ведущую на строку в [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/);
- список ссылок на страницы, где, с большой вероятностью, это строка может появиться.

> [image: Интерфейс]

Если вы все еще не участвовали в переводе сайта, но всегда хотели, [страница пропущенных строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing) – отличная отправная точка, а наличие контекста, поможет даже самым опытным в переводе участникам. Переходя по ссылке на [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/) вы сразу попадаете на окно перевода строки.

Comment: Сюда входит непроверенный перевод?

Comment: @VenZell Если строка еще ни разу не была подтверждена, да. Неподтвержденные улучшения существующих строк, скорее всего сюда не попадают.

Comment: Я так понял, тут еще не все строки выводятся? Непереведенных и непроверенных суммарно около 1000.

Comment: @VenZell Не все строки и не все места их использования. Алгоритм выбора строк для вхождения в эту страницу, к сожалению, мне не известен.

Comment: Хорошо, а как часто будут забираться строки на проверку? Сейчас при сортировке "по адресу" все "заспамлено" строкой `site design / logo ©`. Она переведена

Comment: @VenZell Проверкой строк занимаются участники, имеющие статус ревьюверов. На данный момент это: NickVolynkin, VladD и я. Как только я понимаю, что есть новые проверенные строки, я загружаю их на сайт.

Comment: @VenZell Если необходимо пройтись и выставить флаг «проверено» у строк, пожалуйста, напишите об этом в чате.

Comment: Круто, очень круто.

Comment: Ура! Наконец-то! Это мегафича.

Comment: можно попросить добавить время последнего обновления [этой страницы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing)? (чтобы понимать насколько актуальна информация, а то я вижу переводы, которые были утверждены 5 дней назад, но до сих пор показаны в списке отсутствующих, [пример](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/79591992?key=9e66f900da99f5a0e725348207711a5e)).

Comment: @jfs Отличное предложение! Передал ответственным разработчикам.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky больше не работает?

Comment: @Suvitruf На данный момент страница не отображает пропущенные переводы, хотя должна. Видимо, дефект.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так я пару недель назад про это спрашивал, вы в чате сказали, что напишите разрабам )=

Comment: @Suvitruf Ага, написал. Говорят, что все работает, но мы видим, что нет.

Answer (score 2):

На текущий момент функционал отключен. Причины не ясны. На вопрос в поддержку ответа не последовало: [Untranslated strings page is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323989/339911)